# Which Python VMs, and versions, include a GIL, and which don't?

Tags: python, gil

I see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Concurrency/) that CPython 2.*, 3.[01] and PyPy 1.4.1 all have a GIL. 
CPython 3.2 has an improved GIL. etc... It's fairly comprehensive, but not exhaustive, and seems a bit out of date. Is that page the best resource for this information, or is there a more up-to-date page somewhere?

Comment: Removing the GIL would be a major new feature proudly broadcast through all available channels (if it had ever happened), so you can safely assume all later versions of a Python w/ GIL still have a GIL unless you find evidence of the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All versions of CPython have a GIL.

Stackless Python (which is based on CPython) also has a GIL

All release versions of PyPy have a GIL; the removal of the GIL (through "software transactional memory") is under consideration but I don't believe anything has been released yet, even in nightlies.

Neither IronPython nor Jython, which run on the Microsoft CLR and on the Java VM respectively, have a GIL.